# What is the difference between the following two python methods?

Tags: python

What is the difference between these 2 fragments of python codes?
I want to check whether an array contains the integers 1,2,3 in sequence as its elements?

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if(i <= (len(nums)-3)):
            if (nums[i] == 1 and nums[i+1] == 2 and nums[i+2] == 3):
                return(True)
    return(False)
```

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-2):
        if (nums[i] == 1 and nums[i+1] == 2 and nums[i+2] == 3):
            return(True)
    return(False)
```

The first one gives wrong answer for the array:

```
arrayCheck([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,3])
```

but the second one is correct.

Comment: `for i in nums:` isn't iterating over the indices, it is iterating over the actual list items.

Comment: for i in nums: here "i" does not contain the index value, "i" contains list items value. "in" operator iterates over items, not indices.
let input is [1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,3].
In the first iteration,
i=1,i+1=2,i+2=3
so, nums[1]=1
nums[2]=2
nums[3]=1
.
.
.
.
.
In the last iteration,
again,i=1,i+1=2,i+2=3
and again you're accessing nums[1],nums[2] and nums[3]!
But you expected to check nums[6],nums[7],nums[8].
Every time when i=1 you are accessing the indices 1,2 and 3.That's why you're getting
this error.
In the second function you're accessing the index values,so it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block `i` is elements of the parameter. The second, it's only their indices.

If you wanted the first to iterate over indices rather than the elements, use this

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    for i, _ in enumerate(nums):
        if i <= len(nums)-3:
```

You can also use list slicing, by the way

```
if nums[i:i+2] == [1,2,3]:
    return True
```